# Proving Bounded variation is smallest linear space

Tags: vector-spaces, bounded-variation

Prove that $BV[a,b]$ is the smallest linear space containing all monotone functions on $[a,b].$

Comment: Try to write a function of bounded variation as the difference of two monotone functions. On the other hand, prove that monotone functions are of bounded variation.

Comment: @K.Stm. as any montone function $f=f-0$ the other one is trivial isn'T it ?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis What do you mean?

Comment: @K.Stm. ah sry I used my hint, which makes it trivial

Comment: If $V_a^x f$ denotes the variation of $f$, write $f(x)= V_a^x f-(V_a^x f-f(x))$. Show that both $V_a^x f$ and   $V_a^x f-f $ are non-decreasing functions. This, together with the fact that monotone functions are of bounded variation, will imply your result.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
You can use a result from the Jordan-Decomposition which states that $f$ is of bounded variation iff $f=f_1-f_2$ where $f_1,f_2$ are non decreasing functions.

Answer (score 0):

Let f,g in V,V is the set of all bounded variation functions on [a,b]

Let S is a linear space contains  all monotonic functions of [a,b]

It is clear that V is linear(since cf and f+g in V)
" f is a function of bounded variation on [a,b] iff it can be expressed as the difference of two montonic increasing functions "

f= (f+g)-g   implies f+g and g are monotonic functions on [a,b]
Then f+g & g  in S
f+g in S implies f also in S
Thus f,g are in S This follows V is a subspace of S

Comment: Please use Latex